# Is it possible to use awslog with gitlab-ci autoscaling runners?

Tags: docker, logging, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-machine

gitlab-ci autoscaling runners use docker-machine to scale. There are settings that can be passed through the [runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) section and the [runners-machine](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersmachine-section) section of config. In the runners-machine section, docker-machine [driver options](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/) can be passed. Of these, `--amazonec2-monitoring` is one, but the documentation on it is pretty sparse. It doesn't really say what the accepted settings are, just that the default is `false`. Because there's not really any kind of explanation of how it works, I'm not really sure what it should be set to in order to enable it.

I tried `true`. I also used the `--amazonec2-userdata` driver option, which I verified is successfully being executed with `docker info`, which shows the default driver is `awslogs`.

However, when gitlab creates a new instance, and I log into it through docker-machine while a job is running, I can see that the job is set with the log driver of `json-file`.

Can anyone point me to more info on how to get the docker container started without an overriding log driver? Googling for terms like `docker-machine awslogs amazonec2-monitoring amazonec2-userdata` is yielding very little.

Also, can someone on SO with a reputation of 1500+ consider adding the tags `amazonec2-monitoring` and some kind of tag for `awslogs`, if they're not too specific?

Thanks!